# SVA assert property on posedge of X

Tags: system-verilog

Say if I have a property that gets triggered for checks on the posedge of a clk. What behaviour would it have when that clk is X? does "posedge clk" gets triggered when clk is X? Thanks

Comment: I meant more of a 0->X and X->1 transition being considered as a posedge trigger, and would exercise the property under such scenarios. I got my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0->1, 0->X, and X->1 are all triggers for a `posedge`. There are various ways of filtering if that is not what you want.